# I am unable to pick color picker in winium using c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, automation, winium

I am unable to pick the color in color picker and checkbox in winium driver c#

```
driver.FindElementByName("Dependencies color").Click();
driver.FindElementByName("Basic colors:").Click();
driver.FindElementById("719").Click();
driver.FindElementByName("Hue:").Click();

driver.FindElementByName("Hue:").SendKeys(datawords[5].ToString());
driver.FindElementByName("OK").Click();
```

I have to pick a different color by sending keys.